# SEO Redirect with Node.js Sails

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, sails.js

I'm using Angular and Node.js and I have a redirect for bots to load pages for SEO content. In express I had something like this:

```
req.isBrowser = function () {
  var pattern = /(opera|aol|msie|firefox|chrome|konqueror|safari|netscape|navigator|mosaic|lynx|amaya|omniweb|avant|camino|flock|seamonkey|mozilla|gecko)+/i;
  return pattern.test(req.headers['user-agent']);
};
```

I would use that in that in the GET requests to do necessary redirects. Having trouble to figure out how to do this nicely in Sails though. Is there a place where I can run this check and just auto redirect to either a static file in the public folder if it's a browser otherwise run it through jade/ejs if it's a bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read about sails doc [policies](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies), it talks about how to make authentication for sails. Means they can run a function every time a route is hit.

```
/config
  - policies.js

// policies.js
module.exports.policies = {
  "*": "isBrowser"
      // or some controller
  ViewController: {
    "index": "isBrowser"
  },
}


/api
  /policies
    - create a file name "isBrowser.js"

// sBrowser.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  if (/your logic/) {
    // go back to your normal route function.
    return next();
  } else {
    // do something about SEO bot.
  }

};
```